# MutableLiveData does not notify observer

Tags: viewmodel, observer-pattern, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I am trying to use `MutableLiveData` with pre-filled value from database, but `Observer` always returns `null` as `book`. I need to keep it as `MutableLiveData`, NOT `LiveData`, because I have to set it programatically on some places. Therefore I am calling `setValue` with `LiveData` retrieved from DB. Code:

`ViewModel`:

```
private final MutableLiveData<Book> bookLiveData;

public MyViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    ...
    book = new MutableLiveData<>();
    bookLiveData.setValue(bookRep.getBookLiveData().getValue());
    ....
}
```

`Fragment`:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    getActivity().getBookLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), book -> {
            ... // When fragment is created, book is always null here
    });
}
```

Can somebody tell me why is `Book` null in observer? I thought that `Observer` would be notified when `bookRep.getBookLiveData()` is finished and value is retrieved. THank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bookRep.getBookLiveData().getValue()` will always return `null`. Since you are setting a `null` value in the ViewModel like this: `bookLiveData.setValue(null)` at line 7, `bookLiveData` is always `null` at initial launch.

You cannot use `getValue()` on a `LiveData` object to get value here because it is always null at initialization. You need to *observe* so that you get notified when it actually emits a value.

There are several different ways to solve it. One way is to observe `getBookLiveData()` in the ViewModel using `observeForever()` method.

```
private LiveData<Book> bookFromRep;
private MutableLiveData<Book> bookLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
private Observer<Book> bookObserver = bookLiveData::postValue; // Book observer posts value to bookLiveData.

public MyViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    ...
    bookFromRep = bookRep.getBookLiveData();
    bookFromRep.observeForever(bookObserver);
    ....
}

@Override
protected void onCleared() {
    super.onCleared();

    // Don't forget to remove observer when you use observeForever()
    bookFromRep.removeObserver(bookObserver);
}
```

Another, and arguably a better, approach to this problem is to use [MediatorLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData). I won't include its implementation here but what I recommend is to understand different approaches and find the best approach that fits your need.

Comment: Thank you, I used `MediarorLiveData` following way: 
`bookLiveData = new MediatorLiveData<>();
bookLiveData.addSource(bookRep.getBookLiveData(), b -> bookLiveData.setValue(b));`